# Verifying on my probability approach

Tags: probability

Three different wooden case that contains rotten apple. The case $A$ has a rotten rate of $5\%$, the case $B$ a rate of $3\%$ and the case $C$ $2\%$. Each of the cases has different volumes, with $A$ having $20\%$ of the apples, $B$ having $20\%$ and $C$ having $60\%$. If an apple is selected at random and found to be rotten, what is the prob that the apple came from the $C$ case?

Let me explain how I think :

Assume a number of total apples :  $1000$

$A$  has $200$ total apples and $10$ of them are rotten

$B$ has $200$ total apples and $6$ of them are rotten

$C$ has $600$ total apples and $12$ of them are rotten

Since we know that the found apple is rotten,

$$\text{nCr-rotten-all} = \binom{28}1$$

$$\text{nCr-rotten-C} = \binom{12}1$$

$$\text{result} = \frac{\text{nCr-rotten-C}}{nCr-rotten-all}$$

Is this the right formulation?

Thank you for your clear explanation in advance

Comment: what are we suppose to verify?

Comment: I mean, do you help me how to build the correct formulation?

Comment: When selecting a random apple, do we first select one of the cases with equal probability?

Comment: Each of them would be selected based on their overall status in the set.

Comment: I know that 12/600 belongs to C rotten, 6/200 belongs to B rotten and 10/200 belongs A but I am getting confused to use those all information to go on the right track

Comment: OK, so you know there were 28 rotten apples, and 12 of them were from crate C ... then assuming that each rotten apple could be chosen with equal likelihood, the probability that the rotten apple you picked was from crate C is $\frac{12}{28}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bayes' rule to make your working more readable, let's use $R$ to denote the event that an apple is rotten.

$$P( C | R) = \frac{P(C)P(R|C)}{P(R)}=\frac{P(C)P(R|C)}{\sum_{i \in \{ A,B,C\}}P(i)P(R|i)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, my brain is totally fired :). Can you please show me how to plug in the numbers from the question to the baye's rule?

Comment: your formulation is actually fine. If you want to use Bayes. First identify what are your $P(A), P(B), P(C), P(R|A), P(R|B), P(R|C)$.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to use this as well to compare them. $P(A)=200/100 $  and $P(R|A)=1/10 $  is that right pattern?

Comment: $P(A)=20\%=\frac{20}{100}$, $P(R|A)=5\%=\frac{5}{100}=\frac{1}{20}$.

Comment: That is great, they both give the right answer